# Sticky div at top not letting user scroll down on higher resolution of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

We have a div which we want to pin at the top of the screen when user scrolls down the page. The code works fine on screen resolution till 1600 X 900 but as we go beyond this resolution (eg. 1920 X 1080) the user can not scroll to the bottom and screen tends to move at the top all the time.

This is causing a vibrating motion on the screen as user is trying to scroll down where as something is trying to move the screen at top.

The div has css :

```
.fixedElement {
width:100%;     
 z-index:10000;
 background-color:White;}
```

and to detect the top offset of the document javascript code is

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
var $el = $('.fixedElement'); 
var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && !isPositionFixed){ 
    $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
}
 if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && isPositionFixed)
{
 $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0px'}); 
}
});1028
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Which browser are you using?  Sometimes this type of action varies between browsers.  Have you considered having two different div's, one for the top and one for original location.  Have a interval timer check every tenth of a second to see how far down you are scrolling, and make the fixed div visible or invisible.  You are executing code every time you scroll a single pixel, and that could be a thousand times a second.

Comment: Currently I am using IE11 and chrome and the application will be used on IE11.